# import project for low api, stylev21 not found

Tags: android, github

I research material design project for 4.x API, It seem too many problems in style values, always style.... (in v-21) not found. I think v-21 is only build with api 21. But I want to build for 4.x API, do anyone know problem?

Here is some project in Github i found:

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

https://github.com/rey5137/material

I use eclipse too. Change ANdroid API 21,22,23 but it still not work
 **The Log say : no resource found that matches the given name "TextAppearance.Appcompat.Body1"**
Here is my picture: 
 [image]

[image]

OTHER QUESTION: 
 The Author say this material project can run on API 2.x -> 4.x , but why it need to build with API 21 -> 23? So can lower device can run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `compileSdkVersion 23` or `21 or above` in your `build.gradle` file.

> The Log say : no resource found that matches the given name
>   "TextAppearance.Appcompat.Body1"

This is because you might not have imported AppCompat Library to your Eclipse Project.

> The Author say this material project can run on API 2.x -> 4.x , but
>   why it need to build with API 21 -> 23? So can lower device can run
>   it?

Yes, Its always a good practice to build your App with the latest API version as this will include all the updated resources which might be not available in previous versions of Android. However, this will not affect your APK size in anyways.

Comment: According to your screnshot, you have not set AppCompat Library to your Main project. please do this.